# image getting shifted in chrome while using background-attachment:fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

my background image is getting shifted in chrome with background-attachment:fixed when i am using chrome...... but it is working fine with firefox .please help me out...

[image: in chrome]

[image: in firefox]

```css
.bkimg1
{
    background-image: url('justice-league1.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    background-position:top;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    max-width:1100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bkimg1">
            <div class="text">
                <div class="border">
                    WELCOME EVERYONE
                </div>
                <input type="button" value="Get Started" onclick="init(),scrolldownpage('profiles')"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

*Thanks*

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `background-position` property.:

```
backgroun-position: center;
```

Please have a look at this link for further details.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp